# Change text color in first row of spinner

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner. When user clicks on it a dialog box appears with several rows and text inside that rows to choose from. The default text inside spinner is `Select facility`. And the first row text is the same i.e. `select facility`. Now what I want is to change the text color in first row in spinner dialog box i.e. the color of select facility.

How can I achieve this?

Here is the code where I believe I can change it.

```
if (position == 0 && hideFirstText) {
        ((TextView) convertView).setText(R.string.select_facility);
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_green);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Here is what I already tried

```
            ((TextView) convertView).setTextColor(4737352);
```

But above solution completely removes the first row text.

I also tried this

```
    convertView.setTextColor(4737352);
```

But convertView does not have setTextColor() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should override the getView method,,like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when dialog opens it internally calls getDropDownView so customize this method of your adapter  like this

```
public View getDropDownView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(position == 0){
            //Do custom stuff here like find textview & change textcolor
        }
        return(row);
    }
```